# Is it possible to pass a component as props and use it in a child Component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In a Vue 2.0 app, let's say we have components A, B and C.

A declares, registers and uses B

Is it possible to pass C from A to B?

Something like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="A">
    <B :child_component="C" />
  </div>
</template>
```

And use C in B somehow.

```
<template>
  <div class="B">
    <C>Something else</C>
  </div>
</template>
```

The motivation: I want to create a generic component `B` that is used in `A` but receives from `A` its child `C`. Actually `A` will use `B` several times passing different 'C's to it.

If this approach is not correct, what is the proper way of doing it in Vue?

**Answering @Saurabh**

Instead of passing as props, I tried the suggestion inside B.

```
<!-- this is where I Call the dynamic component in B -->

<component :is="child_component"></component>

//this is what I did in B js
components: {
 equip: Equipment
}, 
data () {
 return {
   child_component: 'equip',
   _list: []
 }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to render Equipment, but the dynamic way

I get 3 errors in console and a blank page

> [Vue warn]: Error when rendering component  at /home/victor/projetos/tokaai/public/src/components/EquipmentFormItem.vue:
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined

Apparently I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Are you sure these errors are coming from these code only, where are you using `setAttribute ` or `name` attribute?

Comment: must be some internal process. I'm not doing it in this app

Comment: I am sending a component over an event bus to a singleton modal in my app and I just render it as `<dialog.content />` with a wrapper for `v-if="dialog.type === 'component'"`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use special attribute `is` for doing this kind of thing. Example of dynamic component and its usage can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

> You can use the same mount point and dynamically switch between multiple components using the reserved  element and dynamically bind to its is attribute.

Here's how `is` can be used with either an imported component or one passed as a prop:

```
<template>
  <div class="B">
    <component :is="myImportedComponent">Something</component>
    --- or ---
    <component :is="myPassedComponent">Something else</component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myImportedComponent from "@/components/SomeComponent.vue"

export default {
    props: {
        myPassedComponent: Object
    },

    components: {
        myImportedComponent
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: not working here, but I don't know exactly what is going on. I Will update my question with more information

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! I would just like to know if that's possible to set custom type of the prop with passed component instead of `Object` type? Something like:

    `passedComponent: { type: Component, required: true },`

Comment: also, is it possible to get the name of the passed component in the component which receives this component via prop?

Comment: I made it work in Vue 3 just using `passedComponent: { type: Function, required: true }`. `Function` is a built-in type in JS, and components are rendered as functions. :D

Answer (score 41):

Summing up:

```
<!-- Component A -->
<template>
  <div class="A">
    <B>
      <component :is="child_component"></component>
    </B>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import B from './B.vue';
import Equipment from './Equipment.vue';

export default {
  name: 'A',
  components: { B, Equipment },
  data() {
    return { child_component: 'equipment' };
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Component B -->
<template>
  <div class="B">
    <h1>Some content</h1>
    <slot></slot> <!-- Component C will appear here -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you. I had a follow-up on this. Now imagine Component C emits an event, and I want to act on it in Component B. I tried to listen for it using v-on on <slot> but that didn't work. What are my options here?

Comment: Got the answer! I would simply listen for the event in the grandparent, i.e. <component :is="child_component" @some-event="handleIt"> instead of listening for it on the slot where it is being injected.

Comment: we must have to import all the child components where we have ` <component :is="child_component"></component>` tag. wouldn't it make it slower if we need only specific child components from parent only. is there any workaround where we can import components in parent and pass it to child?

Comment: @RaviAnand you can register components as async dynamic `async dynamic components` `components: { B, Equipment: () => import('./Equipment.vue')}`,

Answer (score 7):

Here's solution to forward custom component through props of another component

`:is` is special attribute and it will be used to replace your actual component and it will be ignored if you try to use it as a prop in your component. Luckily you can use something else like `el` and then forward this to `component` like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="el">
      <slot />
    </component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'RenderDynamicChild',
    props: {
        el: {
            type: [String, Object],
            default: 'div',
        },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Any valid element you use in `el` attribute will be used as a child component. It can be html or reference to your custom component or `div` by default as specified in component declaration.

Passing custom component to prop is little bit tricky. One would assume you declare in a `components` property of parent component and then use it for `el` attribute but this doesn't work. Instead you need to have your dynamic component in `data` or `computed` property so you can use it in a template as a prop. Also note `AnotherComponent` doesn't need to be declared in `components` property.

```
<template>
  <RenderDynamicChild :el="DynamicComponent">
    Hello Vue!
  </RenderDynamicChild>
</template>

<script>
import RenderDynamicChild from './DynamicChild';
import AnotherComponent from './AnotherComponent';

export default {
  name: "ParentComponent",
  components: { DynamicChild },
  data() {
    return {
      DynamicComponent: AnotherComponent,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Using computed property for your dynamic component allows you to switch between components easily:

```
<script>
import DynamicChild from './DynamicChild';
import AnotherComponent from './AnotherComponent';

export default {
  name: "ParentComponent",
  components: { DynamicChild },
  data() { return { count: 0 } },
  computed: {
    DynamicComponent() {
      return this.count % 2 > 1 ? AnotherComponent : 'article';
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Increase `this.count` to alternate between `AnotherComponent` and simple `article` html element.

Comment: What if you want to pass a reference to the component tag to another component what will then update the passed component?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's too late to answer this question. But I think it could help others with this same issue.

I've been looking for a way to pass components throw others in vue, but it looks that VUE3 have a approach for that using named slots:

Here it's the documentation about that:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#named-slots

Basically you can have:

```
<template>
  <div class="A">
    <slot name="ComponentC"></slot> <!-- Here will be rendered your ComponentC -->
  </div>
  <div class="A">
    <slot name="ComponentD"></slot> <!-- Here will be rendered your ComponentD -->
  </div>
  <div class="A">
    <slot></slot> <!-- This is going to be children components -->
  </div>
</template>
```

And from your `B` component

```
<template>
  <div class="B">
    <A>
      <template v-slot:ComponentC>
        <h1>Title of ComponentC </h1>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:ComponentD>
        <h1>Title of ComponentD </h1>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:default>
        <h1>Title of child component </h1>
      </template>
    </A>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks works in Vue 1.5 perfectly too !!!

Comment: Although this question does not answer the question. It does highlight how one should enable component composition in Vue. This answer might prevent some headache for those newer to Vue.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use another component within your functional component you can do the following:

```
<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import childComponent from './childComponent'
  Vue.component('child-component')
  export default {}
</script>


<template functional>
  <div>
    <child-component/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Reference:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7492#issue-290242300

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Dynamically importing a component in a parent component, so yes, you can do that in Vue3 using:

```
<component :is="child_component" />
```

but to render "child_component" itself dynamically, you can use

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import('./components/MyComponent.vue')
)
```

**Let me give you an example:**

let's say you have several multiple child components (ChildA, ChildB, ChildC) that you want to load dynamically based on what you pass to the parent component (Parent), so the Parent component will be something like this:

**Parent**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{
    childComponent?: string;
}>();
const AsyncComp = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import(`./${props.childComponent}.vue`)
)
</script>

<template>
    <component :is="AsyncComp"/>
</template>
```

and then you can call the Parent component dynamically wherever you want like this:

```
<Parent :childComponent="child-a"/>
<Parent :childComponent="child-b"/>
<Parent :childComponent="child-c"/>
```

For a better explanation, you can check this article:

https://medium.com/@pratikpatel_60309/dynamic-importing-component-templates-with-vue-js-78d2167db1e7