# How to pass a component dynamically as a prop in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
<ComponentA :child-component="ComponentB" />

<ComponentA :child-component="ComponentC" />
```

This is useful if you want to wrap a component with some reusable functionality:

Let's say:

```
<Sortable :child-component="List" />
<Sortable :child-component="Menu" />
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992579/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-component-as-props-and-use-it-in-a-child-component-in-v) is almost there, but is not the same.

Comment: That question seems to be exactly what you need. Just drop the colon so that the prop is a string and you have your value. The other question is just using variables so that it can change the components. Then in your sortable component, use the is prop with the value of your child-component prop.

Comment: Thank you:) I will try it out.

Comment: Yeah, go with `<component :is="name"></component>` - it should do the trick if you pass string.

Comment: You're probably going to encounter issues with setting the properties on the children of the sortable though, since sortable won't know what they are. You may want to investigate [Vue Slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html), might be a better fit for something like this

Comment: @obermillerk That's what I thought first, but then I read that other question and I got confused, like 'maybe there is a better way' using the `is` attribute and as I am new to Vue I am a bit confused. But I will try it out your first suggestion first to see if it works. Thank you :)

Comment: It really depends on what you need, not sure what you're trying to do, but just something to keep in mind

Comment: @obermillerk I am trying to incorporate this [awesome js library](https://shopify.github.io/draggable/) into Vue and make it a component that wrap other components (not HTML elements). I am following along this [video](https://youtu.be/jR3R_m5FPRc). He incorporates vue slots but in his case there are not components, he is working with simple HTML elements, and in my code a `<ul`> is a component.

Comment: Hey @viery365 : I see you have edited your question to include that the suggested duplicate is not an exact duplicate of this question, but you do not tell us how your question differs from the suggested duplicate. To me both questions look very similar, so it is unclear to me what you want to have answered that is not covered in the other question.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Hi, I edited my question but to correct the title of the question and to put an end to a tag. I provided the link for the other question in my first try. And if someone thought is a duplicate question so fast probably was because I provided the link to the other question in the first place.

Comment: There are already several libraries for Vue that do drag sorting and the like that you could use. If you're doing it as a challenge to yourself, you could see if there's an open source one and look know they handle it.

Comment: Also if your sortable component is just a single item in the sorting, then definitely slots are the way to go I would say. The is prop would be more suited for if you were trying to automatically populate the list in some single wrapper component, but if you're looking to add custom rendering to a single sortable element, then you can just leave a slot and let the person using it worry about what goes in it