# What's the idiomatic way to pass component prop to a component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I came from the ReactJS world that has a common way to create flexible components: pass components as prop to other component.

For example:

```
import MyCard from './MyCard';
import Slider from './Slider';

const Example = ({items}) => {
  return <div classname="example"> <Slider cardComponent={MyCard} items={items}/> </div>
}
```

Simple, elegant, clever.

What's the right and idiomatic way to realize this approach in Vue.js?

I don't need an answer how to create `Slider` component, I want to know what is the idiomatic way to pass `MyCard` component to it.

Comment: Vue.js has [_slots_](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass a component as props and use it in a child Component in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992579/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-component-as-props-and-use-it-in-a-child-component-in-v)

Comment: No it's not the duplicate, because Victor asked how to create `Slider` component. I've asked what's *the idiomatic way* to pass component as props to it.

Comment: Slots are not solution, because `Slider` is not able to set needed props to it.

Comment: One of the duplicate's answer mentions dynamic components with Vue's `:is` attribute.

Comment: The other thing is that React and Vue have a different way of achieving what you're trying to do, where in React, there is a lot of HoC that applies props to their children and in Vue, it focuses on composition in the "template" where slots are used most of the time. In the rare case you really want a dynamic component, `:is` is the way to go.

Comment: I know about `:is`, it's all about how to create `Slider` component. I just want to know what is the idiomatic way to pass component prop to it.

Comment: It's either your question is unclear or you're confusing `:is` use.

Comment: Passing the component is a simple prop that takes either a string of the component's name or the component's options object, which `Slider` can then use on a dynamic component inside of its template with `:is`.

Comment: But there is a problem, how to pass non global registered component? As options object? But I should put it in `data` or take it from `$options.component.MyCard` then. I suppose, that it's not beautiful and right way.

What's idiomatic way to do it? Have you encountered libraries that assume this approach?

Comment: What's wrong with having it in the data? The chosen component options object **is** dynamic data. See [this snippet from the Vue documentation](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/b2qj69o1/).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you create your `Slider` component, does it take the path to the component, does it take the component, does it evaluate its children based on passed props, does it have slots, mixins?

My guess to this is:

*.html

```
<template id="example-template">
  <div class="example">
    <slider :items="items">
      <template #cardSlot="{requiredAttr1, requiredAttr2}">
        <my-card :attr1="requiredAttr1" :attr2="requiredAttr2">
      </template>
    </slider>
  </div>
</template>
```

*.js

```
import MyCard from './MyCard';
import Slider from './Slider';
export default {
  template: '#example-template',
  name: "Example",
  props: ["items"],
  components: {
    MyCard,
    Slider
  }
}
```

[Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

```
//slider component
<div class="slider"">
    <slot 
        name="slotname" 
        :passedPropName="sliderValue"
     >
    </slot>
</div>

//extended slider component
<slider>
    <template 
        #slotname="passedPropObj"
    >
        <mycomp 
           :propName="passedPropObj.passedPropName" 
        /> 
    </template>
</slider>
```

[Dynamic & Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.)

Comment: How to pass additional props at the `Slider` component to `MyCard` component if I will use this approach?

Comment: I able to freely modify `Slider`.