# How to access child's props from wrapper component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a bunch of Vue components on the marketing website. There are stateful and functional (aka stateless) components. For example badge and button. I need to create a wrapper component for a testing purpose, that takes any component, renders that component but additionally adds a table below with props-values, passed along with child component. For instance:

```
<XButton hello="hi" :some-other-prop="2" label="Hey">You Will Never Appear</XButton>
```

will be rendered to a Button tag with the information below:

```
 <button>Such text with label Hey</button>
 some-other-prop | 2 
 label           | Hey
```

**Button.js**

```
Vue.component('XButton', {
  name: 'XButton',
  functional: true,
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Default text',
    },
  },
  render(createElement, context) {
    return createElement('button', context.data, 'Such text with label ' + context.props.label);
  },
});
```

**Wrapper.vue**

```
<template>
   <div>
    <slot/>
   </div>    
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   functional: true,
   props: {
     listPropsOfDoubleNestedChild: {
       type: Boolean,
       default: false
     }
   },
   render(createElement, context) {      
     const vNode= context.props.listPropsOfDoubleNestedChild
      ? context.children[0].children // or even get props of double nested child
      : context.children[0];

     if (vNode.componentOptions) {
       console.log("Props of nested stateful component", vNode.componentOptions.propsData);
     } else {
      console.log("Props of nested stateless component are not reachable thru componentOptions", vNode.componentOptions);
     }

      return null;
  }
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
  <template>
     <Wrapper>
        <XButton hello="hi" :some-other-prop="2" label="Hey">You Will Never Appear</XButton>
     </Wrapper>
  </template>
```

So, I can only get passed props of the stateful component.

Some screenshots:

**Stateful component:**
[image: Stateful]

**Functional component:**
[image: Stateless]

In React it is very simple to accomplish with `React.Children.only(props.children).props` and what about Vue?

Comment: So, something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992579/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-component-as-props-and-use-it-in-a-child-component-in-v

Comment: Not at all. It's not about passing props to the child, it is about getting props of the stateless child.

Comment: So, the question title sounds like we want to pass the component as a prop. Wich solves the wrapper portion. And then "accessing props of a stateless child".... Can we reword this in Vue terms? My guess is we want to have that layer in the child component based off the parent .. Or presentational components.