# Components handed via props in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue 2 I had a custom routing solution that involved in some cases handing in components as props.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="component" :data="componentData"/> 
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        component: {}
        componentData: {}
    }
}
</script>
```

In vue 3 this gives the warning: "Vue received a Component which was made a reactive".

Is there a way of avoiding this warning?  Is it possible to dynamically add components to a component?

If you have an array of components that is not globally registered in App.components is it possible to render them without warnings?

Here is an older question about this in Vue2:
[Is it possible to pass a component as props and use it in a child Component in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992579/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-component-as-props-and-use-it-in-a-child-component-in-v)

Note the above code works fine in Vue2, this question is specifically about Vue3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to stop the errors appears to be to wrap my component or list of components in markRaw prior to setting on data.  This stops vue3 making it reactive.

[Mark Raw](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#markraw)

```html
<script>
import Page1     from './pages/page1.vue'
import Page2     from './pages/page2.vue'
import Page3     from './pages/page3.vue'
import Page4     from './pages/page4.vue'
import Page5     from './pages/page5.vue'
import {markRaw} from "vue"

const components = markRaw({
    Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5
})

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            components
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you also explain what it means to mark it raw?